# Motion: Drawing a Line from an Origin to a Destination in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a graphic that plots a map of the United States using coordinates stored in `Map2.csv`. Then I add the great lakes using information from `Water.csv`. I then have origin and destination coordinates for various shipments that were made stored in `data1.csv`.

I want processing to draw a line from origin to destination slowly enough that you can track the path of the shipment with your eye. I'd like there to be a sequential element so the lines could be drawn in certain orders by sorting the `data1.csv`file accordingly, but that's not a necessity.

Written as is, the lines draw very nicely, however my map of the US will not draw and I get an error stating 
`The sketch has been automatically resized to fit the screen resolution` If I delete `P2D` from `size(1620,1080, P2D)`the map will draw, but the lines will no longer move.

My code is below along with links to the relevant data.

```
Table data;
PShape plot;

long current;

int x;
int y;

void setup(){
  size(1620, 1080, P2D);
  background(55);
  smooth();


    // Draw US Map

  String[] lines = loadStrings("Map2.csv");    // File containing coordinates to plot US Map
  stroke(55);
  strokeWeight(1);
  smooth();

  String[] pieces = split(lines[0], ',');

  for ( int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    fill(0);

    beginShape();
    current = int(pieces[0]);

    while ( current == int(pieces[0]) & i < lines.length) {

      x = int(pieces[2]);
      y = int(pieces[1]);
      vertex(x, y);
      i++;

      if ( i < lines.length) {
        pieces = split(lines[i], ',');
      }
    }
    endShape();
  }



  // Add Lakes to Map


  String[] lines2 = loadStrings("Water.csv");    // File containing coordinates to plot great lakes
  smooth();

  fill(22, 25, 180);

  String[] pieces2 = split(lines2[0], ',');
  for (int i = 0; i < lines2.length; i++)
  {

    fill(110);
    beginShape();
    current =  int(pieces2[0]);

    while (current == int(pieces2[0]) & i < lines2.length) {

      x = int(pieces2[2]);
      y = int(pieces2[1]);
      vertex(x, y);
      i++;
      if (i < lines2.length) {
        pieces2 = split(lines2[i], ',');
      }
    }
    endShape();
  }





  //create a group to store the lines from each row
  plot = createShape(GROUP);
  //load the data, specifying it has a header and it's tab separated
  data = loadTable("data2.tsv", "header, tsv");
  //traverse each row
  for (TableRow row : data.rows ()) {
    //extract each value
    int x1 = row.getInt("x1");
    int y1 = row.getInt("y1");
    int x2 = row.getInt("x2");
    int y2 = row.getInt("y2");
    //add the coordinates as lines to the group
    PShape line = createShape(LINE, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    plot.addChild(line);
  }
  shape(plot);
  strokeWeight(1.0);
}
void draw(){
  //hacky fade effect, change the alpha/transparency value to experiment with fade amount 
  background(55);
  int r = 65;
  int g = 255;
  int b = 35;
  stroke(r, g, b);
  //animate the trajectories
  //use normalized (between 0.0 and 1.0) value to traverse the paths (think of it as 0 and 100%, 0 is at the start 100% is at the end)
  //if can be interactive
  float traversal;
  if(mousePressed) {
    traversal = map(mouseX,0,width,0.0,1.0);
  }else{//or time based, up to you :)
    traversal = map(sin(frameCount * 0.01),-1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0);
  } 
  beginShape(LINES);
  //for each trajectory
  for(int i = 0 ; i < plot.getChildCount(); i++){
    PShape line = plot.getChild(i);
    //access each line's start and end points
    PVector start = line.getVertex(0);
    PVector end   = line.getVertex(1);
    //calculate the linearly interpolated point in between start end using the traversal value and lerp()
    PVector inbetween = PVector.lerp(start,end,traversal);
    //use the interpolated value to draw
    stroke(64);
    vertex(start.x,start.y);
    stroke(160);
    vertex(inbetween.x,inbetween.y);
  }
  endShape();
}
```

Data:
 [Map2
[Water](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tNXd_-VgYV3URLBpGfn_vaf54S7gHknPH-QaKx2dyiU/edit?usp=sharing).](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E1Xy48hGHheSlQddejNoW8EZYpP3LQl-7GXPy4Eis1k/edit?usp=sharing)

data1
<"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QzbCGW8H6PZgLkmWN8OyplVNTJhp3tlPGxR_Zv6lttM/edit?usp=sharing">

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple questions here, but I'll try to go through them one at a time.

> Written as is, the lines draw very nicely, however my map of the US will not draw and I get an error stating  `The sketch has been automatically resized to fit the screen resolution.`

My best guess is that Processing can't create windows that are bigger than the resolution of the screen. You can create a full-screen application, but really it shouldn't matter: you shouldn't tie yourself to one screen size; you should write your code so any window size will work. More on that later.

Anyway, to get rid of your first error, let's just use a smaller size:

```
size(810, 540, P2D);
```

[image]

But now you only see some of your lines, since you're always drawing to the same coordinates regardless of the window's size. Let's change that.

Notice these lines at the end of your `draw()` function:

```
stroke(64);
vertex(start.x,start.y);
stroke(160);
vertex(inbetween.x,inbetween.y);
```

Notice that you're using the `x` and `y` values of the `vertex` directly. This will only work as long as your window and vertex values are using the same scale. Instead, you should **scale** your vertex values so that they take into account the `width` and `height` of the window. One way to do that is this:

```
stroke(64);
vertex(width/1620.0 * start.x, height/1080.0 * start.y);
stroke(160);
vertex(width/1620.0 * inbetween.x, height/1080.0 * inbetween.y);
```

[image]

Cool, now we've got your lines drawing in a more reasonable scale. Next problem:

> however my map of the US will not draw

Notice where you're drawing your map. You're only drawing it **once**, in your `setup()` function. But then you just draw over it in the `draw()` function with the `background()` call, so you never see it!

Since you're drawing the map and lakes as you load the file, doing that from the `draw()` function will slow your sketch down. Instead of moving any of your logic around, you could just **draw your map and lakes to a `PGraphics` in `setup()`, then just draw that `PGraphics` in your `draw()` function.**

To do that, you first have to declare a `PGraphics` variable at the top of your sketch:

```
PGraphics mapGraphics;
```

Then you'd change your drawing code to use that `PGraphics` instead:

```
  // Draw US Map
  String[] lines = loadStrings("Map2.csv");    // File containing coordinates to plot US Map

  mapGraphics = createGraphics(width, height);
  mapGraphics.beginDraw();
  mapGraphics.stroke(55);
  mapGraphics.strokeWeight(1);
  mapGraphics.smooth();

  String[] pieces = split(lines[0], ',');

  for ( int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    mapGraphics.fill(0);
    mapGraphics.beginShape();
    current = int(pieces[0]);

    while ( current == int(pieces[0]) & i < lines.length) {

      x = int(pieces[2]);
      y = int(pieces[1]);
      mapGraphics.vertex(width/1620.0 * x, height/1080.0 * y);
      i++;

      if ( i < lines.length) {
        pieces = split(lines[i], ',');
      }
    }
    mapGraphics.endShape();
  }

  // Add Lakes to Map
  String[] lines2 = loadStrings("water.csv");    // File containing coordinates to plot great lakes
  mapGraphics.smooth();
  mapGraphics.fill(22, 25, 180);

  String[] pieces2 = split(lines2[0], ',');
  for (int i = 0; i < lines2.length; i++)
  {
    mapGraphics.fill(110);
    mapGraphics.beginShape();
    current =  int(pieces2[0]);

    while (current == int(pieces2[0]) & i < lines2.length) {

      x = int(pieces2[2]);
      y = int(pieces2[1]);
      mapGraphics.vertex(width/1620.0 * x, height/1080.0 * y);
      i++;
      if (i < lines2.length) {
        pieces2 = split(lines2[i], ',');
      }
    }
    mapGraphics.endShape();
  }
  mapGraphics.endDraw();
```

Notice that I've also added the logic for scaling the map- otherwise, your map would be too big for the window!

Then you just need to draw that `PImage` from your `draw()` function:

```
void draw() {
  //hacky fade effect, change the alpha/transparency value to experiment with fade amount 
  background(55);
  image(mapGraphics, 0, 0);
  //...
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very helpful!